# WorkManager PeriodicWorkRequest run twice

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have an app that runs a database refresh every 15 mins.

The PeriodicWorkRequest is enqueued in onCreate of my main activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    updateDatabasePeriodically();


public void updateDatabasePeriodically() {
    PeriodicWorkRequest updateDatabaseRequest =
            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UpdateDatabaseWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(getMainActivityContext()).enqueue(updateDatabaseRequest);
}
```

UpdateDatabaseWorker:

```
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    // Do the work here--in this case, upload the images.


    updateDatabase();
    // Indicate whether the task finished successfully with the Result
    return Result.success();
}

private void updateDatabase() {
    AppDatabase appDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(context);

    Log.i(TAG, "Updating alerts at: " + DateTimeHelper.getHumanReadableTime(now));
}
```

The problem is that the work is done twice every time the job executes as can be seen by my log statements

```
2019-11-22 10:20:23.185 24987-25085/com.package.myapp I/com.package.myapp.UpdateDatabaseWorker: Updating at: 22/11/2019 10:20:23
2019-11-22 10:21:30.510 25309-25408/com.package.myapp I/com.package.myapp.UpdateDatabaseWorker: Updating at: 22/11/2019 10:21:30

2019-11-22 10:34:49.642 25309-26180/com.package.myapp I/com.package.myapp.UpdateDatabaseWorker: Updating at: 22/11/2019 10:34:49
2019-11-22 10:35:23.372 25309-26198/com.package.myapp I/com.package.myapp.UpdateDatabaseWorker: Updating at: 22/11/2019 10:35:23
```

Why is this happening? Should I be creating the request somewhere else?

Would this be a good solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53059601/9137086

I feel like that's a treating the symptom instead of the disease

Comment: These are most likely previous tasks you have scheduled without canceling.  The first and fourth log seem to be one repeating job (~15min delta) - the others are most likely from previous `onCreate`s in your activity.  You may have to save the requestId to keep track if one is in progress.  The referenced answer seems like a good approach.

Comment: Okay, I will implement the referenced answer and go with that unless/until another solution is suggestested

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this cases please, use an [`uniqueWorkRequest`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/unique-work), otherwise (especially for PeriodicWorkRequest) you will end up with duplicates.

```
public void updateDatabasePeriodically() {
    PeriodicWorkRequest updateDatabaseRequest =
            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UpdateDatabaseWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(getMainActivityContext())
        .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("uniqueWorkName", 
                           ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                           updateDatabaseRequest);
}
```

You can take a look at the reference for [`WorkManager#enqueueUniqueWork`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#enqueueUniqueWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest)) for more information on the call and on the [`ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy) one to see which are the options.

If you don't have requirements to use REPLACE, please use KEEP, it's less expensive and avoid stopping an already working Work.

Comment: I had to use `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork()` instead of `enqueueUniqueWork()`

Comment: Thanks! You're absolutely right, I updated the code.